# access to time or current frame in OSL

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, osl

I'm trying to create an OSL shader which will select a different texture depending on which frame I'm rendering.

I don't need it to be in OSL but I have a mixture of texture groups each with a series of texture maps and I want to render every combination of each of them.

I thought I could setup a loop and iterate through an array to do so but I can't seem to figure out how to access the current frame information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the frame info you could create a simple OSL script:

```
shader frame_node(
    int  frame= 1,
    color Color1 = color(0.8, 0.0, 0.0),
    output color Diffuse = 0)
{
    Diffuse = frame * Color1;
}
```

and keyframe the frame input socket accordingly. 
e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I've done, I just thought there might be a more direct way to get at that info from OSL.  Thanks for the clear example.

Comment: The OSL-specification https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/doc/osl-languagespec.pdf mentions on page 40, global variables: `float time: Current shutter time for the point being shaded.` ,
`float dtime: The amount of time covered by this shading sample.`,
`vector dPdtime How the surface position P is moving per unit time.` Which is not helpful as well as attributes accessible: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/OSL#Attributes